# Rails loop through params array and save records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, loops, associations

Ok, so i have two tables in my postgresql database that are involved with my issue:

```
Table: roles

Fields:

|    id    |    name    |    description    |    active   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|          |            |                   |             |


Table: role_permissions

Fields:

|    id    |    role_id    |    permission_id    |
--------------------------------------------------
|          |               |                     |
```

Permissions themselves are stored in a separate `permissions` table that acts as a definition table.

Here is what my model relationships look like:

```
Role:
    has_many :role_permissions, :dependent => :destroy

Role_Permission:
    belongs_to :role
```

The form i have to create a new `role` look something like this:

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @role], html: {role: "form"}) do |f| %>
  <%= render "admin/shared/error_messages", obj: @role %>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>General Information</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name, "Role Name" %>
      <span class="help-block">Used to identify the role in code files.</span>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :description %>
      <span class="help-block">What is this role used for?</span>
      <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Role Permissions</legend>
    <% @permissions.each do |p| %>
      <label>
        <%= check_box_tag "role[role_permissions][][permission_id]", p.id %>
        <%= p.name %>
      </label>
    <% end %>
  </fieldset>
  <%= f.submit "Save Role", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <%= link_to "Cancel", :back, class: "back-btn" %>
<% end %>
```

Saving a new role (with a few permissions selected) gives me these available `params[]`:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"*******=",
"role"=>{"name"=>"Test Role",
"description"=>"This is a test role",
"role_permissions"=>[{"permission_id"=>"1"},
{"permission_id"=>"9"},
{"permission_id"=>"10"},
{"permission_id"=>"11"}]},
"commit"=>"Save Role"}
```

I can use this to save the role itself:

```
@role = Role.new(role_params)
if @role.save
  flash[:success] = "Role has been successfully created!"
  redirect_to admin_roles_path
else
  setup_subnav("users")
  flash[:danger] = "Something went wrong! Please try again."
  render :new
end
```

The part I am a little confused about is how to get the `role_permissions` param array to save as individual records in the `role_permissions` table.  As you can see, I need to save them with their `permission_id` and the "parent" `role_id`.

How can I get the form to save individual `role_permissions` records?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: which version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your Role model

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :role_permissions
```

In your controller

```
def role_params
    params.require(:role).permit(:name, :description, {:role_permissions_attributes => [:permission_id]})
end
```

In view:

```
<%= check_box_tag "role[role_permissions_attributes][][permission_id]", p.id %>
```

It should create a role_permission record for each hash inside the role_permissions array in the param

**Update:**

In edit form

```
<%= check_box_tag "role[role_permissions_attributes][][permission_id]", p.id, role.role_permissions.collect(&:permission_id).include?(p.id) %>
```

Comment: I added that to my role.rb model and it saved the `role`, but not the `role_permissions`.  Do i need to touch anything in the form above or the `create` action in the `roles_controller`?

Comment: Saw your update, still isn't saving the `role_permissions`...is this line in the form correct? `<%= check_box_tag "role[role_permissions][][permission_id]", p.id %>`

Comment: Looks like, it needs to be `role_permissions_attributes`. Updated my answer

Comment: So, that got it to save correctly...however, on my `edit` action, the checkboxes are not checked by default. Do i need to manually do that on this line somehow? `<%= check_box_tag "role[role_permissions_attributes][][permission_id]", p.id %>`

Comment: Thanks for the update!  You sir, are awesome!  My last question, i promise.  When i uncheck something that was previously checked i'd like it to be deleted from the `role_permissions` database.  Should i just delete everything from that table that has that `role_id` and then re-add anything that is checked?  If i save more than once it creates duplicates....that would alleviate that problem as well.

Comment: FYI, to help with the deletions and duplicates i just added this to the `update` action: `RolePermission.where("role_id = ?", params[:id]).delete_all` before the role is updated so it'll just delete them all and add back the correct ones.

Answer (score 0):

Add in Role

accepts_nested_attributes_for :role_permissions
AND
attr_accessible :role_permissions_attributes

Tip: A similar functionality but the approach is different

https://github.com/prasadsurase/dynacan

Role:
has_and_belongs_to_many :permissions

Permission:
has_and_belongs_to_many :roles

PermissionsRoles:
belongs_to :role
belongs_to :permission

in view

```
<%= check_box_tag "permissions[]", role_permission.id, @role_permissions.include?(role_permission.id), { array: true} %>
```

Comment: My app actually uses rails 4 so `attr_accessible :role_permissions_attributes` won't work.